# pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims, I deployed milvus server using

Tags: kubernetes, server, persistent-volume-claims, milvus

etcd:
enabled: true
name: etcd
replicaCount: 3
pdb:
create: false
image:
repository: "milvusdb/etcd"
tag: "3.5.0-r7"
pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

service:
type: ClusterIP
port: 2379
peerPort: 2380

auth:
rbac:
enabled: false

persistence:
enabled: true
storageClass:
accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
size: 10Gi

### Enable auto compaction

### compaction by every 1000 revision

autoCompactionMode: revision
autoCompactionRetention: "1000"

### Increase default quota to 4G

extraEnvVars:

- name: ETCD_QUOTA_BACKEND_BYTES
  value: "4294967296"
- name: ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL
  value: "500"
- name: ETCD_ELECTION_TIMEOUT`enter code here`
  value: "2500"

### Configuration values for the pulsar dependency

### ref: https://github.com/apache/pulsar-helm-chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1hLr.png)

I am trying to run the milvus cluster using kubernete in ubuntu server.
I used helm menifest https://milvus-io.github.io/milvus-helm/

Values.yaml
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/milvus-io/milvus-helm/master/charts/milvus/values.yaml

I checked PersistentValumeClaim their was an error
no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Comment: please share commands you used, the errors you faced and your effort to understand and resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

This error comes because you dont have a Persistent Volume.
A pvc needs a a pv with at least the same capacity of the pvc.

This can be done manually or with a Volume provvisioner.

The most easy way someone would say is to use the local storageClass, which uses the diskspace from the node where the pod is instanciated, adds a pod affinity so that the pod starts allways on the same node and can use the volume on that disk. In your case you are using 3 replicas. Allthough its possible to start all 3 instances on the same node, this is mostlikly not what you want to achieve with Kubernetes. If that node breaks you wont have any other instance running on another node.

You need first to thing about the infrastructure of your cluster. Where should the data of the volumes be stored?

An Network File System, nfs, might be a could solution.
In this case you have an nfs somewhere in your infrastructure and all the nodes can reach it.

So you can create a PV which is accessible from all your node.

To not allocate a PV always manualy you can install a Volumeprovisioner inside your cluster.

I use in some cluster this one here:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner

As i said you must have already an nfs and configure the provvisioner.yaml with the path.

it looks like this:

```
# patch_nfs_details.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nfs-client-provisioner
  name: nfs-client-provisioner
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nfs-client-provisioner
          env:
            - name: NFS_SERVER
              value: <YOUR_NFS_SERVER_IP>
            - name: NFS_PATH
              value: <YOUR_NFS_SERVER_SHARE>
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-client-root
          nfs:
            server: <YOUR_NFS_SERVER_IP>
            path: <YOUR_NFS_SERVER_SHARE>
```

If you use an nfs without provvisioner, you need to define a storageClass which is linked to your nfs.

There are a lot of solutions to hold persitent volumes.

Here you can find a list of StorageClasses:

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/
```

At the end it depends also where your cluster is provvisioned if you are not managing it by yourself.